# insert in Linked List Turbo C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to program a text editor in C. I am having trouble with inserting an element in a linked list. The program simply won't insert anything in the middle of the linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
```

I used singly linked list.

```
struct node {
struct node *previous;
int c;
int x;
int y;
struct node *next;
}*head;
```

this works fine:

```
void characters(int typed, int xpos, int ypos)      //assign values of a node
{
struct node *temp,*var,*temp2;
temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp->c=typed;
temp->x=xpos;
temp->y=ypos;

if(head==NULL)
{
    head=temp;
    head->next=NULL;
}

else
{
    temp2=head;
    while(temp2!=NULL)
    {
        var=temp2;
        temp2=temp2->next;
    }
    temp2=temp;
    var->next=temp2;
    temp2->next=NULL;
}

}
```

this works just fine too.

```
void printer()                          //to print everything
{
struct node *temp;
temp=head;
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    gotoxy(temp->x,temp->y);
    printf("%c",temp->c);
    temp=temp->next;
}

}
```

this works just fine too:

```
void deletesEnd                  //delete at the end
{
struct node *temp,*last;
temp=head;
last=temp;
while(temp!=NULL && temp->next!=NULL)
{
    last=temp;
    temp=temp->next;
}
if(last==temp)
    {
        free(temp);
        head=NULL;
    }
else{
free(last->next);
last->next=NULL;
}
}
```

**THIS IS THE PROBLEM:**

```
 void checker(int ch, int xpos, int ypos)
{
int flag=0;
struct node *temp,*temp1,*insert_node;
temp=head;
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    if(temp->x==xpos && temp->y==ypos)
    {
        temp1=temp;
        temp=insert_node;
        insert_node->c=ch;
        insert_node->x=xpos;
        insert_node->y=ypos;
        insert_node->next=temp1;
        flag=1;
        break;
    }

    else
        temp= temp->next;
}
free(temp);
free(temp1);
if(flag==0)
    characters(ch,xpos,ypos);
}

main()
{
int c;                          //for storing the character
int x,y;                    //for the position of the character
clrscr();
for(;;)
{
    c=getch();
    x=wherex();
    y=wherey();
    if(c==27)
        exit(0);

    else if(c==0|| c==224)
    {
        switch(getch())
        {
            case 72:                    //for up
                    gotoxy(x,y-1);
                    break;
            case 80:                    //for down
                    gotoxy(x,y+1);
                    break;
            case 75:                    //for left
                    gotoxy(x-1,y);
                    break;
            case 77:                    //for right
                    gotoxy(x+1,y);
                    break;
         }
    }

    else if(c==13)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }

    else if(c==8)                       //for backspace
    {
            deletesEnd();
            clrscr();
            printer();

    }

    else                        //for normal characters
    {
        checker(c,x,y);
           //   characters(c,x,y);
        printer();
    }
}
}
```

I tried to debug it, it goes inside the loop with the conditional statement of ((temp->x==xpos && temp->y==ypos)) Thus, the program is supposed to insert an element but it doesn't. :(

Comment: It means it is not entering in the if statements, let me check

Comment: I've checked it seriously - but I found myself unable to find the problem cause, In my opinion it is only possible if your linked list is empty, because only then control flow can skip through if statements, try to validate your x and y position data in your linked list.

Comment: First of all, stop using Turbo C (it is a 20 year old compiler). Also, the code you've written is non-standard C.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to `malloc` a `struct node` for the element you want to insert first, not just declare a `struct node *`.

Try to add `struct node *insert_node = (struct node *)malloc(struct node)` in your checker method.

Answer (score 0):

Try concept of insertion from this one - It can insert a node from front end

Just make a new pointer to node and name it create

```
struct node *create;

int item;
printf("Enter a number you want to insert\n\t");
scanf("%d",&item);
create = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
create->info = item;
create->ptr = first;
HEAD = create;
```