# Insert in Linked List C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working on a simple text editor in C. I am having troubles with inserting an element in a linked list.

Here is my structure:

```
 struct node {
 struct node *previous;
 int c;
 int x;
 int y;
 struct node *next;
 }*head;
```

Here is my insertion code:

```
void checker(int ch, int xpos, int ypos)
{
    int flag=0;
    struct node *temp,*temp1,*insert_node=NULL;
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
   {
        if(temp->x==xpos && temp->y==ypos)
        {
            insert_node->c=ch;
            insert_node->x=xpos;
            insert_node->y=ypos;

            if(temp->previous==NULL) //this is for inserting at the first
            {
                   insert_node->next=temp;
                   head=insert_node;
            }

            else                     //this is for inserting in the middle.
            {
                            temp1=temp;
                temp=insert_node;
                insert_node->next=temp1;
            }

                flag=1;
                            break;
            }
                temp=temp->next;
        }

//this one's for the normal insertion and the end of the linked list.
if(flag==0)
    characters(ch,xpos,ypos);
}
```

None of the inserting in the first and middle works. I do not know where it went wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Where is your `structure`???

Comment: opps sorry i forgot, i will update it.

Comment: in your code for inserting at first..insert_node->left should be null as it is the first node now

Comment: @user2624491... I suggest you to re-write your check conditions. 1:if head=NULL, 2: check for last element, 3: insert in middle...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042984/insert-in-linked-list-turbo-c

Comment: @Coffee_lover... Good catch...Same question by same OP...

Comment: You allocate a node and put the address into temp, then you assign the contents of head to temp. You can use this as an excuse to learn about GDB, or any debugger that is applicable by the way, it will save you some time and agony very soon. DDD for XWindows, also gives you a graphical view of the contents of nodes, and can show linked lists pretty good.

Comment: @Krishna Even edited by the same guy

Comment: @Coffee_lover... Only friendship and groups matter... Belated Happy Friendship Day...

Answer (score 4):

```
temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp=head;
```

You are allocating space for a new node, but then you loose the address of this new node assigning `temp=head`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `insert_node` is a local variable in your function checker() which is also initialized as NULL. Doing `insert_node->c` means `NULL->c` which i'm sure you'll agree with me that is wrong.

Try to dynamically allocate memory for your variables before using them and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`insert_node` will always be NULL in the code you posted.

Also, you may want to split your code more; start by isolating part of it in a `find()` function.